# Use of express-session and JWT

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, jwt

I have a bunch of questions about express-session and JWT in a project that I am building.

I have an Express API server that I want to protect using some sort of API key, to make sure only authorized applications can access to my data. JWT would probably get the job done. However I also need to authenticate users and restrict them from accessing certain parts of the data (e.g. role-based permissions) using express-session.

The frontend server would be a Next.js instance, which would save and use the cookies for express-session. The session would be stored in a MongoDB instance.

Would I be able to use both authentication methods in the same project? Would it be secure? Is there any easier approach to this? How could I implement the permissions?

Any help and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all JWT can store session data you can save it into cookie or use `localStorage` or any client side storage for getting the data. Sessions should not be stored in DB in any way due fact  it needs to be refreshed due security reasons. You can save in JWT authorization which should be added to token upon login also store in token user id and any other info which you need e.g username email etc BUT NOT PASSWORD.

Comment: Auhtorization needs to be done separatly - creating user create authorization in db (depends soly on you how you are going to do it e.g. "admin", "user" or using integers like 1 = admin 0 = guest ). and as i stated before saving that reference into token upon login then checking on every reqest on backend for user.authorization and do whatever you wanna do..send different data for instance

Comment: @Maielo So by using exclusively JWT I could handle user authentication and app authentication? Would this work with cross-domian requests? My api and frontend servers are hosted separatedly, so that's one of my concerns.

Comment: yes JWT is basically JSON string with signed hashed behind data. It doesnt matter where you send it. Reccomend you to use header in your request `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 3):

JWT and Express-Session both accomplish the same thing. The difference is a browser does not allows a http-only cookie to be accessible through javascript. At then end they are both used for the same end.

The jwt should be related to a session of a user, therefore the users permissions are the ones that matter. These can be implemented in a DBs and related to the user. Does he has this permission or does his role has this permission is the middleware you would put on the routes.

In case of doing it with express-session, I would personally take the same approach.

Comment: Using express-session + JWT is redundant, I guess.

Comment: It seems obvious now, but as a beginner it took me a while to determine I needed to 1) store the user ID in the JWT payload, 2) up the user in each route that required security, 3) store the user in the req object so that information about the user is available to the rest of the route's processing.